# watchdog in directory monitoring is not working

Tags: python, watchdog

I want to watch a folder for addition, modification and deletion of file and execute a command whenever any of this event occurs.

I found this tutorial  that helped https://www.michaelcho.me/article/using-pythons-watchdog-to-monitor-changes-to-a-directory
so here is the code I now have

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler



class Watcher:
    DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH = "/Users/***/desktop/google drive/protpics"


    def __init__(self):
        self.observer = Observer()


    def run(self):
        event_handler = Handler()
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()
        try:

           while True:
               time.sleep(5)

        except:
            self.observer.stop()
            print("Error")

        self.observer.join()


class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    @staticmethod
    def on_my_event(event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None

        elif event.event_type == 'created':
           #Take any action here when a file is first created.
           print ("Recived created event - %s" % event.src_path)

        elif event.event_type == 'modified':
            # Take any action here when a file is modified.
            print ("Recieved modified event - %s" % event.src_path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    W = Watcher()
    W.run()
```

the problem now is that when I added a new file to the directory no message gets printed out. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you figure out the difference between your code and example's? In your link, the author use `on_any_event`, but you are using `on_my_event`. There isn't a method named `on_my_event`.

Have a check at official document: http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html#watchdog.events.FileSystemEventHandler